# bool vs void* casts on the same object

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

The code below prints 'operator bool' when used in the if statement and 'operator void*' when it needs a bool for function call.

Why isn't it using `operator bool` for the function call too? And how to make it use it in both cases?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        std::cout << "operator bool" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    operator void*() const
    {
        std::cout << "operator void*" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

void f(bool valid)
{
    std::cout << "f called " << valid << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;

    if(a)
        std::cout << "if a" << std::endl;

    f(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `explicit` from `operator bool`. Or explicitly cast (e.g.: `f(static_cast<bool>(a));` )

Comment: If you `operator bool()` returns true exactly when your operator `void*()` returns a non-null pointer, then you don't need the `operator bool()`. In my experience, it's usually better to have as little conversions allowed as possible, as you can get ambiguous conversions quite quickly otherwise. And I'd question any design that lets `operator bool()` be anything different from `(void*)object != nullptr`.

Comment: The example above does not reflect exactly the actual code I was dealing with. Instead of void* it had an actual pointer to a C structure. but now that I am thinking I might not need the bool() one if there is a cast to pointer which itself implicitly casts to bool right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In an `if` statement, implicit and explicit conversion operators are considered. Because `A` has an `operator bool`, it chooses that one, as it is a better match than converting `A` to a `void*` and then converting that to `bool`.

But in every other statement, which are not conditions (`if`, `while`, ...), the explicit conversion operators do not participate in overload resolution, and the only valid operator then is `operator void*`, which can be used because there is an implicit conversion from pointers to `bool`.

If you want `operator bool` to be selected, you need make it non-`explicit`, or use a cast (because that's what marking it `explicit` means, making sure that one has to be explicit to use it):

```
f(static_cast<bool>(a));
```

Comment: A reference can be found at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) for the interested.

Comment: why then removing const from the operator void*() const and explicit from operator bool makes it pick void* for both cases?

Comment: @unvadim That's because a non-`const` member function is always a better match than a `const` one (promotion to `const` has to happen).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the operator is declared with the function specifier `explicit`.

In the condition of the if statement the value is contextually converted to the type bool.

From the C++ Standard (4 Standard conversions)

> 2 [ Note: expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted
>   to other types in several contexts:

...

> — When used in the condition of an if statement or iteration statement
>   (6.4, 6.5). The destination type is bool.

However when the value is passed to the function as an argument there is used the so-called copy initialization. In this case the function specifier explicit prevents converting to the type bool.

From the C++ Standard (12.3.2 Conversion functions)

> 2 **A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is
>   only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization**
>   (8.5). Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use
>   in assignments and initializations.

A simple way to force calling the bool operator is the following

```
f( bool( a ) );
```

Comment: is bool(a) equivalent to static_cast<bool>(a) ? which is more C++'ish?

Comment: @unvadim The both are C++ style castings. I would prefer the record bool( a ). It is more readable.